# looping through inbox and save attachments

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin

I am trying to find an e-mail on a certain day and save the attachments. My code is below.

The problem I have is the when debugging none of the items in my inbox are of type MailItem despite me seeing them in my inbox. What am I missing?

**Update**

In debug when I look at oFld.Items.Count it shows 4890 which is the number of the emails in my inbox. Think I'm not using item.GetType part correctly

```
public void SaveAttachment(DateTime dateEmail, string emailSubject, string saveLocation)
        {
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace oNs = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oFld = oNs.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            foreach (object item in oFld.Items)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(Outlook.MailItem))
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem oMail = (Outlook.MailItem)item;

                    if (oMail.ReceivedTime < dateEmail)
                        return;

                    if (oMail.ReceivedTime.Date == dateEmail)
                    {
                        if (oMail.Subject.Contains(emailSubject))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < oMail.Attachments.Count; i++)                                
                                oMail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(saveLocation + oMail.Attachments[i].FileName);                                
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What type *are* they?

Comment: system.__ComObject when I enter the item.GetType().ToString() in the immediate window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    foreach (object item in oFld.Items)
    {
        MailItem mailItem = item as MailItem;

        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            //blablabla
        }
    }
```

It seems to work for some people.

Comment: thanks that works. What would happen though if the item was a appointmentItem and not a MailItem, would it throw an exception?

Comment: No, casting using "as" returns null when the variable is not of the casted type.